# auto_now_add creates a NotNullViolation in Django unit test

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I am trying to set up a unit test for a view that creates 3 objects for use in methods:

```
class TestIssuerSelected(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.i1 = Issuer(issuer_name='Issuer 1')
        cls.i2 = Issuer(issuer_name='Issuer 2')
        cls.i3 = Issuer(issuer_name='Issuer 3')
        cls.i1.save()
        cls.i2.save()
        cls.i3.save()
```

This setUpTestData creates objects from the following model:

```
class Issuer(models.Model):
    issuer_name = models.CharField()
    obj_created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(
        'Date created', auto_now_add=True, editable=False
    )
```

However, it produces the following error:

> sycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column
> "obj_created_datetime" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing
> row contains (8, null, Issuer 2).

What could be going on here? `auto_now_add` should not allow a null field, but it is clearly the error occurring. Of note, this error only seems to occur when I run it in sequence with another test before it that sets up the same setUpTestData. In isolation, this does not occur.

How can I debug this?